# AngularDart specify fontface from package

Tags: css, angular-dart

How do I specify the `@fontface` URL when the font is in a package? After using `webdev build` the font is at `build/packages/<package>/font.ttf`, but before that I'm not sure how to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out just starting the url at `packages/<package>/<path-to-font>` works.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url('packages/<my-package>/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```